# How does the `a` tag behave?

Tags: html, svg, hyperlink, tags

Could you explain how the a tag behaves in this example? Why is it so small?

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="https://facebook.com/starbucks">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="valign-middle absoluteCenter" focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<path></path>
<circle class="sb-icon-hover" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="transparent" r="75%"></circle>
</svg>
  </a>
</li>
```

[image]

Also, could you explain, how to fix it? And how to center it inside the block? Thank you!

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a working demo; but I did add the CSS as otherwise there was no visual content to the `<a>` element. Please update the code if you want to make it more accurately representative of your specific code, and to have it visually similar to the posted image of the running code. Incidentally, an `<li>` element must be wrapped in either a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` element.

Comment: You may need to add display:block for the `a`. Also you can give `a `a size (width, height)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you think the a tag should be large? Where do you think sizing is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor element (`<a>`) is by default an inline element. It will have the height of the font (example 1). So, making a border around it will display the height of the font.

If you set the display of the `<a>` to inline-block or block (example 2 and 3) the element will "contain" the child elements (except if you limit the height...). With either one you can set properties like border, background, padding, margin etc.

```css
svg {
  display: inline; /*default*/
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a {
  display: inline; /*default*/
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a {
  display: block;
}

li {
  margin: .1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/starbucks">default
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red" r="50%"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/starbucks">inline-block
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red" r="50%"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/starbucks">block
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red" r="50%"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```